# Describing a two person game with a pay-off matrix where i have to change the order to of utlities to find a different action profile?

Tags: game-theory

I understand what weakly dominated strategies are, I understand action profiles, 3 player payoff matrixes and utilities, but I cannot seem to figure out what exactly is asked.

The utilities should be such that, by applying in two different orders the iterated
elimination of weakly dominated strategies, two different and unique action profiles are returned.

Can someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 0):

This is getting at the fact that the result of the iterative removal of weakly dominated strategies can depend on the order of removal. Consider the game

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
& L & R \\ 
\hline
A & (10, 4) & (5, 4) \\ \hline
B & (0, 1) & (4, 6) \\ \hline
\end{array}

Depending on the order of elimination, the set of strategies that remains after iterative removal of weakly dominated strategies can be $\{A, L\}$ or $\{A, R\}$. Note that both of these are Nash equilibrium's, but by using iterative removal of weakly dominated strategies we lose one of them.

For a 3x3 example this game has four Nash equilibrium  $(A, L), (B, L), (C, L), (B, R)$. By using iterative removal of weakly dominated strategies we can get $(A, L), (B, L), (C, L)$ depending on the order of removal.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
& L & M & R \\ 
\hline
A & (0, 2) & (1, 0) & (0, 0) \\ \hline
B & (0, 1) & (0, 0) & (1, 1) \\ \hline
C & (0, 1) & (0, 1) & (0, 1) \\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm stuck at coming up with a 3x3 game where by doing IEWDS, I have different outcomes with different action profiles which are unique. I have tried many different ways for about 3 hours now. This is what I have so far. Could you suggest me the best way to approach this? I uploaded a picture as an answer.

Comment: I added an example 3x3 game that can have 3 different outcomes as well as resulting in eliminating one Nash equilibrium.

Comment: Thank you so much! This clarifies everything.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I can't seem to delete the weakly dominated strategies further in attempt number 2. Other ones I've tried have ended up 1 being unique, the other one appearing. I have no clue how to best approach this.